# Find index in a long[] array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have an array of type long[] with 19 sets of digits, and then another array of type char[], when the user inputs "45324" i need to find the index of that input in the long[] array and pass the index to the char[] array and then output the value at that location.

So 45324 index may be 12 and the 12th item in the char[] array may be '#' i tried loops but pfft I'm just failing at every attempt. I would prefer not having to rewrite the code and hardcode all those values again in to a different kind of array..

Comment: Please post your current code and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: Look into the `Array.IndexOf()` method and then use the array indexer to access the char array... done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int index = Array.IndexOf(array, long.Parse("45324"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < longArray.Length; i++)
{
  if(longArray[i].ToString() == input)
  {
    return i;
  }
}

return -1;
```

Comment: Why loop when we have `Array.IndexOf` available?

Comment: @davenewza - Showing an alternative, low level method. Not all answrs have to be the same.

Comment: Very true, but some alternatives are much less convoluted than others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.IndexOf` to determine the index of a value in an array.

```
long numberValue;

// First parse the string value into a long
bool isParsed  = Int64.TryParse(stringValue, out numberValue);

// Check to see that the value was parsed correctly
if(isParsed)
{
    // Find the index of the value
    int index = Array.IndexOf(numberArray, numberValue);

    // Check to see if the value actually even exists in the array
    if(index != -1)
    {
        char c = charArray[index];
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `long` parameter to `TryParse` should be an `out` parameter. The above will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
long input = Int64.Parse("45324");
int index = Array.IndexOf(long_array, input);
char output = default(char);
if(index != -1)
  output = char_array[index];
```

Or:

```
long input = Int64.Parse("45324");
int index = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < long_array.Length; i++){
    if(long_array[i] == input){
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
char output = default(char);
if(index != -1)
   output = char_array[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data doesn't change much you could convert your results to a dictionary using **Linq** allowing you to perform speedy looks based on the user input strings.

assuming that your long array is called `longs` and your char array is called `chars`

```
var dict=longs
         .Select((x,i)=>new {Key=x.ToString(),Value=chars[i]})
         .ToDictionary(x=>x.Key,x=>x.Value);
```

Now you can check using your input strings...

e.g.

```
if (!dict.ContainsKey(userInput)) // value not in the collection
```

or

```
char value= dict[userInput];
```